# Minors of a Vandermonde matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I am working with the $n$x$n$ Vandermonde matrix where the "$\alpha_i$'s" form the set of integers from 1 to $n$.  That is entry $a_{ij} = i^{j-1}$,

What I would like to know is if I delete an equal number of rows and columns is the resulting square matrix always invertible?  If possible it would be nice to have a formula for the determinant of this minor matrix.  I do know the determinant of the large matrix to be $\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} i!$.  It would be sufficient if I can be sure that the minor determinants are all nonzero and bounded above by this.

Edit: Thanks to Csystemguy we know that they are in fact all invertible. Now the question is can we say anything about the determinants of the minors? It would be sufficient if we can bound the minor determinants by the large determinant

Comment: Cross-posted at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/240294

Answer (score 4):

It does. Since $a_{ij}$ are all positive and also distinct for all $i$, you can conclude that the determinant is NOT zero (in fact, positive). In brief, it is the product of the traditional Vandermonde determinant multiply by a symmetric Schur polynomial.

I had the same question before and someone gave me the right answer. See the link below to my question.

[Rank of square matrix $A$ with $a_{ij}=\lambda_j^{p_i}$, where $p_i$ is an increasing sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1781867/rank-of-square-matrix-a-with-a-ij-lambda-jp-i-where-p-i-is-an-incre)

Comment: Can you elaborate on how it is the product of a schur polynomial and the vandermonde determinant? I looked at the Wikipedia page for schur polynomials so have a basic understanding. Which ones do we need to multiply by for which minor?

Comment: It is quite long, but I found the proof here: [Generalized Vandermonde determinants, Toeplitz matrices and Schur Functions](www.math.unipd.it/~demarchi/papers/res-math1.ps)!

Comment: Bruce Sagan's book [The Symmetric Group](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387950679) covers this material.