# Prove that every minor in a matrix is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Let $\zeta_p=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{p}}$ where $p$ is a prime. Let $C=
\begin{pmatrix}
\zeta_p^{0 \times 0} & \zeta_p^{0 \times 1} & \dots & \zeta_p^{0 \times (p-1)} \\
\zeta_p^{1 \times 0} & \zeta_p^{1 \times 1} & \dots & \zeta_p^{1 \times (p-1)} \\
\vdots  &      \vdots &  & \vdots \\
\zeta_p^{(p-1) \times 0} & \zeta_p^{(p-1) \times 1} & \dots & \zeta_p^{(p-1) \times (p-1)}
\end{pmatrix}.$
Prove that every minor in this matrix is invertible.

This matrix can be viewed as the character table of $\mathbb{Z}_p$, which may be helpful.

Comment: Perhaps there is an easy answer. If so disregard this. I think a relevant reference is exercise 17 of para 3 of chapter one of Macdonald's "Symmetric Functions and Hall Polynomials".

Comment: I just added an appendix to my answer, with new unsolved questions...

Answer (score 2):

For the DFT matrix $F_{p}$ of size $p$ where 
\begin{eqnarray*}
(F)_{m,n}=\exp\left(\jmath \frac{2 \pi }{p}  \right)^{(m-1)(n-1)}
\end{eqnarray*}
 is circulant.  The inverse matrix $\left(F^{-1} \right)_{m,n} = \frac{1}{p} \exp\left(-\jmath \frac{2 \pi }{p}  \right)^{(m-1)(n-1)}$.  I don't know if there is a formula for any circulant matrix, but for DFT matrix, the inverse of a submatrix (i.e., any $p-1 \times p-1$ submatrix of $F_{p}$  can be expressed 
in terms of the inverse DFT matrix.

Let $G_{[u,v]}$ is the submatrix of $F$  by puncturing the row $u$ and column $v$ of the matrix $F$. Then we can establish that,

\begin{eqnarray*}
\left(G_{[u,v]}^{-1} \right)_{m,n} &=& \frac{1}{p} \frac{\exp\left(\jmath \frac{2 \pi}{p} \right)^{m n} -\exp\left(\jmath \frac{2 \pi}{p} \right)^{m u + n v - u v}  }{\exp\left(\jmath \frac{2 \pi}{p} \right)^{m+n-1}}, m,n \in [1,p-1]
\end{eqnarray*}

I don't know how easy it is to prove this generically for any circulant matrix (playing around this a bit for some small circulant matrices beyond DFT, it does seem to have a nice structure). It will be nice if the community can get together to prove this and expand further.  For the DFT matrix, this does hold.

Here is a matlab code snippet, if you wish to play with.

```
% G     --- The G=minor(F,m,n), which is a submatrix of F, where row m and 
%           column n are punctured. Claim is that C=inv(G)
N=4;                % DFT siize
w=exp(1i*2*pi/N);    % DFT nernem
F=dftmtx(N);         % DFT matriix
invF=inv(F);         % iiDFT matriix 
G=F;

P=zeros(size(F));
for ii=1:N
    for jj=1:N
        G=F;
        G(ii,:)=[];
        G(:,jj)=[];
        invG=inv(G);
        C=[];
        for n=1:1:N
            for m=1:N
                C(m,n)=1/N*(w^-(m+n-1).*(w^(n*m)-w^(n*ii+jj*m-ii*jj)));
            end
        end
        C(ii,:)=[];
        C(:,jj)=[];
        C=C.';
        P(ii,jj)=max(sum(abs(invG-C)));
    end
end

MaxErr=max(P(:))>1e-10
```

Comment: I would advise you to take for $N$ a prime number (in your program). Like you, I am a Matlab programmer. You will be hopefully interested by the general program (slightly cousin of yours) using $w$ as a symbolic variable I just added to my initial answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** (04-25) : This (Vandermonde) matrix is well known as the Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) matrix.

This issue is in fact established as the **Chebotarëv theorem on roots of unity** (there are other theorems by the same mathematician). See [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0312398.pdf) for an accessible proof ; [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebotarev_theorem_on_roots_of_unity), I found a reference to this [excellent text](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.116.9409) giving (see "Problem" page 5) with a proof using $p$-adic framework. Recent developments [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.07648.pdf).

---

Here is separate proof for the case of $(p-1) \times (p-1)$ minors I had given at first.

The DFT matrix $C$ of order $p$ has the property that

$$C\bar C=pI \tag{1}$$

where the bar means "complex conjugate" (see "The Unitary matrix" in [this reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform)).

Remark : an immediate consequence of (1) is that $|\det(C)|=\sqrt{p}\ne 0$.

Otherwise said

$$C^{-1}=\frac1p \bar C$$

As $C^{-1}$ is $\dfrac{1}{\det(C)}$ times the transpose of the comatrix of $C$, it follows that the cofactor (and as a consequence, the minor) of entry $C_{mn}$ has the form $k \overline{C_{mn}}$ with $k \ne 0$.

---

Edit (04-30) : One can understand the structure of the $\binom{p}{s}^2$  determinants of all the $s \times s$ submatrices of the $n \times n$ matrix $C$ by taking an example in the low-dimensional cases:

$$ p = 5 \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ s=3, \ \ \text{with notation : } \ w=e^{2i\pi/p}$$

These $10^2$ determinants (some of them listed below, obtained by a Matlab program given at the end) have common properties :

- there common degree in "variable" $w$ is $p-1=4$ and
- they are all divisible by $(w-1)$

(I have no proof for these properties).

$$\begin{array}{rr}    -(w - 1)(2w^3 + 2w^2 + 1),&  (w + 1)(w - 1)^3\\
                 (w - 1)(w^2 + 3w + 1),& (2w^2 + 2w + 1)(w - 1)^2\\
                w(w - 1)(2w^2 + w + 2), &       w(w - 1)(2w^2 + w + 2)\\
                w(w - 1)(w^2 + 3w + 1), &       w(w - 1)(w^2 + 3w + 1)\\
          \cdots & \cdots  \\
                  (w - 1)(w^2 + 3w + 1), &        -(w - 1)(w^3 + 2w + 2)\\
         -(w - 1)(w + 1)(2w^2 + w + 2), &    -(w - 1)(2w^3 + 2w^2 + 1)\\
                 -(w - 1)(2w^2 + w + 2), &     (w^2 + 2w + 1)(w - 1)^2\\
                  (w - 1)(w^3 + 2w + 2), &         (w - 1)(w^2 + 3w + 1)\\
               -(w^2 + 2w + 2)(w - 1)^2, &               (w + 1)(w - 1)^3\end{array}$$

Had we taken $s=4$, we would have seen that all the determinants are even divisible by $(w-1)^2$ !

The generic Matlab program :

```
clear all:
p=5; % modulus
s=3; % size of submatrices (s<p)
syms w; % symbolic variable
[X,Y]=meshgrid(0:(p-1));C=w.^(X.*Y); % will be DFT matrix
li=p*(p-1)*(2*p-1)/6; % upper bound for polynomial's degrees
S=nchoosek(1:p,s); % all combinations with s elements out of 1..p
[nc,~]=size(S); % nc = number of combinations.
k=1;
for n=1:nc;
   I=S(n,:);
   for m=1:nc
      J=S(m,:);
      d=det(C(I,J)); % det. of submatrix defined by index sets I,J
      %e=subs(d,w,exp(i*2*pi/p));plot(e,'pr');
      for q=1:li
         d=subs(d,w^q,w^(mod(q,p))); % property w^p=1
      end;
      D(k)=factor(d);k=k+1;
    end;
end;
D.', % array of all determinants
```

The different minors of a same category can be represented graphically (uncomment for that the line beginning by e=subs(...)) : here is for example the plot corresponding to the $100$ values above.

[image]

Here is the plot corresponding to the case $p=7$ for $s=2$ (i.e. $2 \times 2$ minors). Once again, one finds a perfect symmetry :

[image]

And the plot for the  case $p=7$ for $s=5$ (i.e. $5 \times 5 minors) :

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I still don't know how to prove minors  from cofactors of entries.

Comment: The formula connecting coffactors and minors is "cofactor of $C_{m,n} = (-1)^{m+n} \times $ minor of $C_{m,n}$" (if the indices begin at $m=n=1$). As your problem deals with the fact that minors are $\ne 0$, it is equivalent to work on the issue "cofactors $\ne 0$".

Comment: @JeanMarie: what about the smaller minors?

Comment: I realize with your last question that have answered your question was for $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ minors... but not in the general case.

Comment: Connected : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1781912 and https://mathoverflow.net/q/284918.

Comment: Have you already worked on Vandermonde determinants or matrices ?

Comment: I am surprized you are asked such (IMHO) a difficult question for general minors. Are you sure that your question isn't limited to $(p-1) \times (p-1)$ minors ?

Comment: You probably need [Schur polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_polynomial) for the general case (interesting but not evident at all!)

Comment: @JeanMarie: see my comment on the question.

Comment: @JeanMarie: It does ask for all minors. This is an exercise for finite fields, but it is actually about the characters of finite Abelian groups.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Thanks for pointing to this remarkable book. See the reference I have found.

Comment: In fact, there is a much more simple proof [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0312398.pdf)

Comment: I have represented some sets of minors under a graphical form. The symmetry of the results is amazing.