# Pattern of linear independence after applying the Fourier transform of a diagonal projection

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-transform, projection-matrices

Let $U$ be the $N\times N$ unitary matrix that implements a discrete Fourier transform, so that if $v$ is a vector with $N$ complex components (represented by a column matrix), then $Uv$ is its discrete Fourier transform.

Let $\{e_1,...,e_N\}$ be an orthogonal basis in which the components of $U$ are $U_{nm}=\exp(2\pi i\, nm/N)$, let $P$ be a **diagonal** projection matrix of rank $K$, and define the projected vectors
$$
 \tilde e_n \equiv U^{-1} P U e_n.
$$
This defines a set of $N$ vectors, of which only $K$ are linearly independent. If we choose *any* $K$ of these $N$ vectors, are they guaranteed to be linearly independent?

(And if the answer is yes, does this phenomenon have a name?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$U^{-1}$ preserves independence, so we can reformulate your question like this:

Define $PU e_n =: f_n$, and let $V$ be the image of $P$, which is a $k$-dimensional subspace. Is every subset of $\{f_i\}$ of size $k$ a basis for $V$?

Since $V$ was an arbitrary coordinate subspace we can forget about $P$, and just ask:

Does every $k \times k$ minor of the DFT matrix $U$ have a nonzero determinant?

The answer to this is no -- you can find a 2x2 minor of the 4x4 DFT matrix that is the all ones matrix ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix#Four-point ), and this gives an explicit counter example to your question.

However, it seems that there is a very interesting theorem in the spirit of your question:

**Chebotarev's Theorem**: The $n \times n$ DFT matrix has the property that all minors are nonzero if and only if $n$ is prime.

See section 1.1 of [https://pages.pomona.edu/~sg064747/PAPERS/CNMT.pdf](https://pages.pomona.edu/%7Esg064747/PAPERS/CNMT.pdf) for further discussion, or wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebotarev_theorem_on_roots_of_unity

One direction of the theorem can be found by generalizing the 4x4 example.

Comment: Thank you! Seems obvious now. :)

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly Still a great question. I can imagine that if one unpacked the counter example and then generalized to all composite $n$ then its would be natural to wonder about $n$ prime... and then I guess eventually one would at least conjecture Chebotarev's incredible theorem. :-) ( although what I did was google "minors of the dft matrix" after I got to that point, haha )

Comment: There's also some interesting related stuff about minors of Vandermonde matrices, but that wasn't helpful for this problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1781867/rank-of-square-matrix-a-with-a-ij-lambda-jp-i-where-p-i-is-an-incre

Comment: Thank you also for the reference to Chebotarev's theorem. If I understand correctly, it means that the answer to my question would have been yes if I had taken $N$ to be prime.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly Yep, that's how I'm understanding it. Haha, no problem either way -- I'm glad I got to learn an interesting theorem. :-)